# git locally, push to tfs remote repo

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I'm so tired of explaining benefits of using DVCS over CVCS to my teammates. Some of them scared of the learning curve, some of them see no reasons because for them: "tis the same fokin ting". Personally I'm so tired of TFS and its problems. Everytime when I need to work on some small "fix" I have to work on the main dev branch and shelve my stuff in and out, cause branching with TFS so darn painful compared to Git. I have to reconnect my VPN client every single time I switch from ethernet to wifi and that happens a lot.

So I started thinking maybe I could use Git locally and do whatever I want on my local repo, and when the time comes push it to TFS. I know it's possible, but what's the best way to do that? Can I just `git init` the current repo and put the entire `.git` folder into ignored list, so TFS wouldn't check it in or doing just that isn't simply enough?

Until the official update of Visual Studio comes, that will support both git and tfs, I have to use some hacks to do what I want.

Comment: You can still use the officially supported [git-tf](http://gittf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: sounds exactly what I need. The only drawback - it requires Java. Trying it right now. Thanks

Comment: As @DanielHilgarth notes, you want git-tf or git-tfs.  This is unrelated to any official updates to Visual Studio though, since your whole team needs to adopt either TFS or git regardless.  If the team has adopted TFS and you want to use git, you'll need a bridge, always.

Comment: ok... git-tfs worked for me better than git-tf. It's quite slow when you need to pull and push data from\to tfs, but otherwise works! Also I'm using VS2012 update 2 (by the time being it's still CTP hope they soon release it) it has git support through Visual Studio Tools for Git extension

Comment: @Agzam: I'm well aware of the git support.  :)  I'm saying that it wouldn't help in this case where the rest of the team wants to stay with Team Foundation Version Control...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

git-tfs https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs worked for me better. Easy to install. Easy to use. A bit slow though, but if you don't mind that  - works just perfect

Comment: Can you explain a bit how you got it to work? In this line: `git tfs quick-clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/some_project`, why it's not git-tfs? **quick-clone** - does it copy all files for latest version, can I choose not to copy any files and just get folder structure (like TFS), then selectively get latest? Can I only do whole collection or branches? Can I do folders and if yes, how? `$/some_project` does not point to a TFS folder or a Git folder? If TFS, how does it know which Git folder to use for output?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are exactly correct - you just need to deal with .git in TFS.  In general, everything  GIT does is maintained in .git so if you have a way to keep it out of TFS (worst case is move out and then move back) then you can use GIT without problems.

Note that there may be other GIT related files to deal with, .gitignore being the most common example.

I've successfully overlaid GIT and SVN using awareness of .git and related files.  (I know there is a git-svn package; but that wasn't workable for my specific need.)

Also, look into:

```
  git init --separate-git-dir=<other-location-for-dot-git>
```

You'll still need to deal with a symbolic link in the local directory but perhaps TFS issues are easier to deal with.