# Getting started with Git - pull into local repository from a remote TFS server?

Tags: .net, git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I started here, by creating a new local Git repository:

- [Set up Git on your dev machine (configure, create, clone, add)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850445.aspx)

It seems that Visual Studio supports most of the common Git operations. However, I cannot pull the whole folder structure from a remote TFS server. I found a way to push changes to a TFS server, just not the other way around:

[image]

Is there a way to do the initial pull? Preferably without installing any 3rd party software/tools - my company is really anxious about putting any unauthorized apps on the workstation. If not, what are my options?

Also, are there any downsides of this approach? Known issues, etc.

A couple words on why I need this. We have a development branch which gets locked every day for several hours, or more, to allow for build or merge to happen. You can't commit during this time. Also more than one commit per day is considered bad practice here. That's why making another TFS branch would not help much. And no, I don't like using shelvesets. Therefore I would prefer to be able to commit as often as needed, without thinking about code being in a perfectly working state.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15253447/40822

Comment: @dotjoe: Thanks for the link. So one of my options is using a 3rd party [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/) solution, which is a command line tool. I don't think my company will approve this, especially since developer is not Microsoft. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to clone a TFVC repository is to use Git-TF. You do not need to 'install' Git-TF as it is portable.

If your company does not want you to use any third party components then you have only two constructive choices:

1. Convert everything to TFS 2013 Git repos - TFS 2013 supports choosing Git as the server repo.
2. Go work somewhere else - really I would have this as the first option based on your comments. I require that any company I work for/with allow admin locally and to install anything not illegal that I need to do my job efficiently.

Comment: Cloning the whole repository is not an option, since it's too big, and I only need maybe 0.1% of it at all times. Making TFS use Git is not possible, unfortunately, this was my first suggestion. I will consider your option #2, thanks. :) +1 and accepting.

Comment: You can clone a TFVC folder to Git using Git-TF. However we are then back to third party.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [portable Git](https://github.com/bungeshea/GitPortable) version that can rescue in such cases. No guarantees, YMMV.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail on how this solution would help? Thanks.

Comment: My understanding is that you created the repo locally, so you need to setup the remote, but this is not available in VS integration, so you need some additional tool.

Portable means that no setup required, so you need no admin right to "install" the software: you get a nice self-contained directory with a complete git shell.

With Git you can set the remote for your local repo.

Another option is to create the Repo in TFS, pull it down, copy over the files and push it again.

Comment: No I didn't plan on using remote, just stick with the local one, since it's part of VS, which we are allowed to use. Bureaucracy, you know...

Comment: Then rephrase your question: you were talking about a local repo and TFS: or such TFS has a Git repo or you are using TFVC. Be clear!

Comment: I **am** talking about a local Git repo and TFS. TFS is using it's own version control, not Git. There is no remote Git repo, just the local one, which I wanted to use as a buffer.

Comment: No TFS 2013 offer both Git and TFVC (classic TFS version control): that's why the question is ambiguous. You should have specified TFS version.

Comment: Our TFS is 2010, from what I know. But I don't see how this is relevant. If TFS was 2013, it would still be the same TFS, with no option for me to use Git, even though this option exists for the rest of the world.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help, hence upvoted your answer. Sorry, I could not accept it, because it stands more as a comment right now.